# Kohana 3.1 Auth, password field wont generate an error

Tags: php, kohana

My Kohana view file looks like:

```
 <?=Form::open('/signup/user');?>
    <?=Form::label('username', 'Username: ')?>
    <?=Form::input('username', isset($username)?$username:''); ?>
    <br />
    <?=Form::label('password', 'Password: ')?>
    <?=Form::password('password', ''); ?>
    <br />
    <?=Form::label('confirm', 'Re-enter Password: ')?>
    <?=Form::password('confirm', ''); ?>
    <br />
    <?=Form::label('email', 'Email: ')?>
    <?=Form::input('email', ''); ?>
    <?=Form::submit('submit', "Submit"); ?>
<?=Form::close()?>
```

And my controller:

```
public function action_user(){
    if($this->request->method() == "POST"){
        $this->template->set('username', $this->request->post('username'));
        $user = ORM::factory('user');
        try{
            $user->values($_POST)->save();
        }catch(ORM_Validation_Exception $e){
            var_dump($e->errors());
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the latter would accept a form with empty password or non-matching passwords and writes it in Database. The username and Emails field validation works fine but I am not sure how to validate password field.

Comment: Can you post up your user model, we need to see where you have defined the validations.

Comment: I haven't defined any. That what Kohana Auth is about (I suppose). I mean the `Model_Auth_User` has all the validation rules so that I don't have to worry about general forms like Login/Register.

Comment: Well if you can put an empty password in then the Model_auth_user validation are not checking for that, your user model presumably extends model_auth_user?

If so and you dont have enough validation from Auth_User then just define them in your own user model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ai, got the mistake. After reading the documentation of `Model_Auth_User` I got this  written on the rules() method:

> Rules for the user model. **Because the password is *always* a hash when
>   it's set,you need to run an additional not_empty rule in your
>   controller to make sure you didn't hash an empty string.** The password
>   rules should be enforced outside the model or with a model helper
>   method.

Hashing an empty string still return a hash which is *not empty*. So one needs to do the check outside the model, more specifically, on the controller side.